# Unable to use locally installed Protocol Buffers inside ROS

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, ros

I have installed [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) locally. Below is the directory structure of ROS package:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── package.xml
├── include
│   ├── addressbook.pb.cc
│   ├── addressbook.pb.h
│   └── addressbook.proto
├── lib
│   └── protobuf-3.5.0
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

[Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) was installed locally by using `./configure --prefix=$PWD` inside `lib/protobuf-3.5.0` directory.

While compiling the ROS package using `catkin_make`, it seems referring to an old installation of Protocol Buffers and showing version incompatibility errors.

```
[  0%] Building CXX object local_protobuf_ros_example/CMakeFiles/addressbook_protobuf.dir/include/addressbook.pb.cc.o
In file included from /home/bgplvm/ros_ws/src/local_protobuf_ros_example/include/addressbook.pb.cc:4:0:
/home/bgplvm/ros_ws/src/local_protobuf_ros_example/include/addressbook.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^
/home/bgplvm/ros_ws/src/local_protobuf_ros_example/include/addressbook.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^
/home/bgplvm/ros_ws/src/local_protobuf_ros_example/include/addressbook.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^
In file included from /home/bgplvm/ros_ws/src/local_protobuf_ros_example/include/addressbook.pb.cc:4:0:
/home/bgplvm/ros_ws/src/local_protobuf_ros_example/include/addressbook.pb.h:23:35: fatal error: google/protobuf/arena.h: No such file or directory
 #include <google/protobuf/arena.h>
                                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

Although, I put `message(STATUS "Using Protocol Buffers ${Protobuf_VERSION}")` statement inside `CMakeLists.txt` and found that it is using Protocol Buffers 3.5.0. See below the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(local_protobuf_ros_example)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)

set(PROTOBUF_FOLDER ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/protobuf-3.5.0)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    "${PROTOBUF_FOLDER}/cmake/build/release/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/protobuf"
)

find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Using Protocol Buffers ${Protobuf_VERSION}")

catkin_package()
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(addressbook_protobuf include/addressbook.pb.cc)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES} addressbook_protobuf ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

What is missing here? Since I am referring to the local installation, it should work without showing errors. Isn't it?

Comment: Which CMake version do you use? Script `FindProtobuf.cmake` is shipped with CMake. And [the script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindProtobuf.html) which sets `Protobuf_VERSION` variable sets `Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `Protobuf_LIBRARIES` variables instead of ones you use: `PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC. I am using `catkin_make` which is shipped along with ROS Indigo.

Comment: You may check CMake version by output value of [CMAKE_VERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_VERSION.html) variable in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Your set of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is incorrect. It should point to the prefix in which protobuf was installed, not the location of the cmake config file for the package.

So try changing:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    ${PROTOBUF_FOLDER}/cmake/build/release/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/protobuf
)
```

To this:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    ${PROTOBUF_FOLDER}
)
```

That is, assuming `${PROTOBUF_FOLDER}` points to the same location given to the --prefix argument of `./configure --prefix=<INSTALL_PREFIX>`

See the search paths documentation for `find_package` [here.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/find_package.html) (about half way down the page)

I believe if you were on Windows what you had would have worked as `<prefix>/` is one of the search paths for that platform. But on Unix based OS'es you have these as the search paths (per the documentation on above link):

```
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/cmake/<name>*/
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/
```

You also have to be careful about case sensitivity here. Note that in the above paths the last path element they search is `<name>*`. From what I can see in your question it looks like protobuf installs itself under the name of 
 'protobuf', but your `find_package` call is asking for 'Protobuf'. So, try also changing your call to:

```
find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

And finally, as far as I can tell, protobuf doesn't install CMake configs when doing a build via `./configure ...`. To get the CMake configs installed I had to build via CMake by doing:

```
cd protobuf-3.5/cmake
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR> .
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to use locally installed Protocol Buffers.

I just need to set following two variables to locally installed Protocol Buffers:

1. `Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS`
2. `Protobuf_LIBRARIES`

Please see the `CMakeLists.txt` below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(local_protobuf_ros_example)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)

set(PROTOBUF_FOLDER ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/protobuf-3.5.0)

set(Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROTOBUF_FOLDER}/include)
set(Protobuf_LIBRARIES ${PROTOBUF_FOLDER}/lib/libprotobuf.so)

catkin_package()
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(addressbook_protobuf include/addressbook.pb.cc)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES} addressbook_protobuf ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
```

It works as of now. However, I am not sure, if it is a good practice or not. Anyone having a better solution is most welcome.