# Turtlebot3 Ros1 Windows setup issue

Tags: windows, cmake, visual-studio-2019, ros, gazebo-simu

[image]
This is the console output for command catkin_make

I am currently trying to setup a virtual environment for the turtlebot3 based on the windows variation: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/pc_setup/

Setting up Ros1 under windows worked without problems, but the command

> catkin_make

on the turtlebot site gave me an error.
CMakeError:

> Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the
> following output: Change Dir:
> C:/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_af455\fast &&     "C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"
> -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_af455.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_af455.dir\build
>
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_af455.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.obj
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm756D.tmp
>
> CheckIncludeFile.c
>
> C:\ws\turtlebot3\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1):
> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file
> or directory
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077:
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe'
> : return code '0x2'
>
> Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"'
> : return code '0x2'
>
> Stop.

CMakeOutput:

> The system is: Windows - 10.0.18363 - AMD64 Compiling the C compiler
> identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded. Compiler:
> C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
> Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
> Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 0 Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version
> 19.26.28806 for x64 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> CMakeCCompilerId.c Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version
> 14.26.28806.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:CMakeCCompilerId.exe  CMakeCCompilerId.obj
>
> Compilation of the C compiler identification source
> "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CMakeCCompilerId.exe"
>
> Compilation of the C compiler identification source
> "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CMakeCCompilerId.obj"
>
> The C compiler identification is MSVC, found in
> "C:/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/3.17.3/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.exe"
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
> "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded. Compiler: C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Microsoft Visual
> Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
> Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 0 Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version
> 19.26.28806 for x64 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version
> 14.26.28806.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe  CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
>
> Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source
> "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"
>
> Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source
> "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"
>
> The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in
> "C:/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/3.17.3/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"
>
> Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
> Change Dir: C:/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_6bdf7\fast &&     "C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"
> -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_6bdf7.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_6bdf7.dir\build
>
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bdf7.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6A32.tmp
>
> testCCompiler.c
>
> Linking C executable cmTC_6bdf7.exe
>
> C:\opt\python27amd64\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E
> vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_6bdf7.dir
> --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_6bdf7.dir\objects1.rsp
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6B6C.tmp
>
> Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
> Change Dir: C:/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_5fcdd\fast &&     "C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"
> -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_5fcdd.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_5fcdd.dir\build
>
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5fcdd.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6C84.tmp
>
> CMakeCCompilerABI.c
>
> Linking C executable cmTC_5fcdd.exe
>
> C:\opt\python27amd64\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E
> vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_5fcdd.dir
> --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_5fcdd.dir\objects1.rsp
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6CC4.tmp
>
> Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following
> output: Change Dir: C:/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_f8e3d\fast &&     "C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"
> -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_f8e3d.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_f8e3d.dir\build
>
> Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f8e3d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6DEC.tmp
>
> testCXXCompiler.cxx
>
> Linking CXX executable cmTC_f8e3d.exe
>
> C:\opt\python27amd64\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E
> vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_f8e3d.dir
> --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_f8e3d.dir\objects1.rsp
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6E2B.tmp
>
> Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
> Change Dir: C:/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_39a62\fast &&     "C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"
> -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_39a62.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_39a62.dir\build
>
> Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/cmTC_39a62.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6F24.tmp
>
> CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
>
> Linking CXX executable cmTC_39a62.exe
>
> C:\opt\python27amd64\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E
> vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_39a62.dir
> --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
> /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_39a62.dir\objects1.rsp
> @C:\Users\Braun\AppData\Local\Temp\nm6F64.tmp

There is also error text in the console during the command:

> CMake Error at
> opt/rosdeps/x64/share/protobuf/protobuf-targets.cmake:37 (message):
> Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined.
>
> targets defined: protobuf::libprotobuf;protobuf::libprotoc
>
> targets not yet defined: protobuf::protoc

Comment: "There is also error text in the console during the command" - This text **actually** specifies your problem, so you could move it to the beginning of your question post. Others - `CMakeError.log` and `CMakeOutput` are most likely unrelated. Are you sure that the error is **first one** in the output of `catkin_make`.

Comment: Hey, i added the console output now, sorry this should have been there from the start.
This was as far as i see the first and last error in console

Comment: Yes, after some warnings for developers the error "Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined." is the first one. It seems there is some mess in the project about the targets, report the problem to the developers.

Comment: Unfortunate, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Which version of protobuf library did you install in your environment? I can build sccessfully with version 3.6.1. In addtion, please take a look at this topic(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786852/unable-to-use-locally-installed-protocol-buffers-inside-ros).